# snapsvg library - error edge

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

I have a problem with library SnapSVG, because on the chrome and firefox my map works good, but on the edge I have a problem.

This is link to my map
http://adaptsystems.nazwa.pl/projects/hnl/mapa/

My code in html

```
<div class="map-cnt">
            <svg id="svg"></svg>
        </div>

        <div class="map-data">

        </div>
```

My code with SnapSVG documentation

```
var svg = Snap('#svg');
            var activeElement = null;
            var map = [];

            svg.attr({viewBox: "0 0 565 533"});

            var path = svg.path("M147.441 125399 0.125099 0 0.501397 -0.250598 0 0 0.126599 -0.251698 0 0 0.125199 -0.125499 0.125399 -0.125099 0.377197 -0.250898 0.123899 0 0.126599 -0.126299 0.125199 0 0.124199 -0.125399 0 -0.501097 1.00489 -0.126599 0.125199 -0.249398 0.375998 0 0.627696 -0.126599 0.126599 -0.125199 0.625096 -0.125399 0c0,0.418997 -0.984893,0.501397 -1.31609,0.501397z");

            path.data('name', 'Opolski');
            path.data('id', 'path10');
            path.data('gminy', ['ChrzÄ…stowice', 'DÄ…browa', 'DobrzeĹ„ Wielki', 'Komprachcice', 'Łubniany', 'MurĂłw', 'Opole', 'Ozimek', 'NamsĹ‚Ăłw', 'PopielĂłw', 'PrĂłszkĂłw', 'TarnĂłw Opolski', 'Turawa']);
            map['path10'] = path;
        ..............

        there are SVG paths here

        ................

    Snap.plugin(function (Snap, Element, Paper, glob) {
                    var elproto = Element.prototype;
                    elproto.toBack = function () {
                        this.prependTo(this.paper);
                    };
                    elproto.toFront = function () {
                        this.appendTo(this.paper);
                    };
                });

                for (var key in map) {
                    var path = map[key];
                    var name = path.data('name');

                    var bbox = path.getBBox();
                    var text = path.paper.text(bbox.x + (bbox.width / 2), bbox.y + (bbox.height / 2), name).attr({
                        font: '10px Arial',
                        'text-anchor': "middle"
                    });
                    var group = svg.group(map[key], text);
                    map[key] = group;
                }

                for (var key in map) {
                    map[key][0].attr({
                        'fill': '#9EB4D9 ',
                        'opacity': 0.4,
                        'stroke': '#fff',
                        'stroke-width': 2
                    });

                    map[key].mouseover(function (e) {
                        if (this != activeElement) {
                            this.toFront();

                            this[0].animate({
                                'fill': '#55B9FF',
                                'opacity': 1,
                                'stroke': '#3E81D8',
                                'stroke-width': 2
                            }, 600);
                            this[1].animate({
                                'fill': '#fff'
                            }, 300);
                        }

                        //zawsze na koncu wyniesmy aktywny element na sama gore
                        if (activeElement != null) {
                            activeElement.toFront();
                        }
                    });

                    map[key].mouseout(function (e) {
                        if (this != activeElement) {
                            this.toBack();
                            this[0].animate({
                                'fill': '#9EB4D9 ',
                                'opacity': 0.4,
                                'stroke': '#fff',
                                'stroke-width': 2
                            }, 600);
                            this[1].animate({
                                fill: '#000'
                            }, 300)
                        }
                    });

                    map[key].click(function () {
                        if (activeElement != null && activeElement != this) {
                            activeElement[0].data('active', false);
                            activeElement[0].animate({
                                'fill': '#9EB4D9 ',
                                'opacity': 0.4,
                                'stroke': '#fff',
                                'stroke-width': 2
                            }, 600);
                            activeElement[1].animate({
                                fill: '#000'
                            }, 300);
                            activeElement[0].attr({
                                'filter': ''
                            })
                        }

                        activeElement = this;

                        this[0].data('active', true);
                        this.toFront();

                        this[0].animate({
                            'fill': '#768CB0',
                            'opacity': 1,
                            'stroke': '#768CC0',
                            'stroke-width': 2
                        }, 600);
                        this[1].animate({
                            fill: '#fff'
                        }, 300)

                        var f = svg.filter(Snap.filter.shadow(0, 2, 3));
                        this[0].attr({
                            filter: f
                        });

                        var pathName = this[0].data('name');
    //                    $('.map-cnt').append('<span class="loading">Wczytuje dane</span>');

                        var html = '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">';

                        for (var i = 0; i < this[0].data('gminy').length; i++) {
                            html += '<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-' + i + '">' + this[0].data('gminy')[i] + '</a></li>';
                        }

                        html += '</ul><div class="tab-content">';

                        for (var i = 0; i < this[0].data('gminy').length; i++) {
                            html += '<div id="tabs-' + i + '" class="tab-pane fade"><div class="description">' + this[0].data('gminy')[i] + '</div></div>';
                        }

                        html += '</div>'

                        $('.map-data').html(html);
                    });
                }
```

Maybe someone knows how to solve the problem.

Thanks for an answer

Comment: Describe what you have already tried.

Comment: I tried, instead of "for", I gabble the space and id area to make it manually by peaking each id. However, it does not give anything, it is possible that there is a mistake in the library

Comment: 1. Show your code, how you use it. 2. Show what you have in the browser console.

Comment: 1. I've already added the code 2. In console I don't have error.